# Scroll tabs with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a horizontal tab menu. These tabs are all li elements. I show always 5 of them at once. To the left and right I have buttons which scrolls these tabs to either side. I am just not sure how to achieve that. Can I put the next 5 tabs in a different div which will be shown on click? That wouldnt be the best solution, would it? Can I do this somehow with JavaScript or jQuery?

Thanks.

Comment: There is a plugin that already does this: http://jquery.aamirafridi.com/jst/

Answer (score 0):

Make a parent container `div` for the `ul` with `overflow: hidden` and `position: relative` or `position: absolute` and a fixed width. When clicking on next or previous button adjust the left position of the `ul`.

A sample code for reference. Not complete one

***HTML***

```
<button id="prev">Prev</button>
<button id="next">Next</button>
<div id="container">
    <ul id="contentcont">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
         <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
        <li>8</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

***CSS***

```
#container
{
    width: 330px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

#contentcont
{
    width: 1000px;
    position: absolute;
}


#contentcont li
{
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
    height: 280px;
}
```

***jQuery***

```
$(function(){
    $("#prev").click(function(){
        $("#contentcont").animate({'left': '-=110'});
        return false;
    });
    $("#next").click(function(){
        $("#contentcont").animate({'left': '+=110'});
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Adjusting the position of the ul. Could you give me an example please?

Comment: Rahul, how can I tell jQuery not to slide at the beginning or the end when I click a button?